# Add multiprocessing/multithreading method to python web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm scraping job results from a website and storing them in a json file. Now i wanted to speed up my scrape results and i searched over the internet and came to a conclusion that we can do that with multiprocessing/multithreading. I'm not familiar with anyone of them. This is my code and i wanted to add either one of those methods to make my results easier and faster. I don't exactly know which one to use. Can someone please help mse with this question.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import args

results = []
url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=software+developer&l=Bengaluru,+Karnataka&start={}'
with requests.Session() as s:
   for page in range(5):
      res = s.get(url.format(page))
      soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
      titles = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('[data-tn-element=jobTitle]')]
      companies = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.company')]
      data = list(zip(titles, companies))
      results.append(data)


newList = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(newList)
df.to_json(r'data3.json')
```